# Update a nested field with an unknown index and without affecting other entries

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with a layout that looks something like this:

```
    student1 = {
    "First_Name": "John",
    "Last_Name": "Doe",
    "Courses": [
        {
            "Course_Id": 123,
            "Course_Name": "Computer Science",
            "Has_Chosen_Modules": false
        },
        {
            "Course_Id": 284,
            "Course_Name": "Mathematics",
            "Has_Chosen_Modules": false
        }
    ]
};
```

I also have the following update query:

```
db.Collection_Student.update(
    { 
        $and: [
            {First_Name: "John"},
            {Last_Name: "Doe"}
        ]
    },
    { 
        $set : { "Courses.0.Has_Chosen_Modules" : true } 
    }
    );
```

This code will currently update the Computer Science `Has_Chosen_Modules` value to true since the index is hardcoded. However, what if I wanted to update the value of `Has_Chosen_Modules` via the `Course_Id` instead (as the course might not necessarily be at the same index every time)? How would I achieve this without it affecting the other courses that a given student is taking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select any item in the sub array of your document by targeting any property in the sub array of your document by using dot `.`

You can easily achieve this by the following query.

```
db.Collection_Student.update(
  { 
    First_Name: "John",
    Last_Name: "Doe",
    'Courses.Course_Id': 123
  },
  { 
    $set : { "Courses.$.Has_Chosen_Modules" : true } 
  }
);
```

Conditions in search filter are by default treated as `$and` operator, so you don't need to specifically write `$and` for this simple query.